# JQGrid - next and last button are not displaying the fetched data from the local database

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    var firstClick = true;
    $('.editor-date > input').datepicker();
    $('.getdata').click(function () {
        if (!firstClick) {
            $("#GridTable").trigger("reloadGrid");
        }
        else
        {
            firstClick = false;
            $('#GridTable').jqGrid({
                url: '<%= Url.Action("GetData", "Report") %>',
                datatype: 'json',
                mtype: 'POST',
                colNames: ['Log ID'],
                colModel: [{ name: 'LogID', index: 'MessageLogID', key: true, formatter: pointercursor }],
                multiselect: true,
                sortname: 'LogID',
                sortorder: "asc",
                viewrecords: true,
                pager: '#pager',
                rowNum: 20,
                rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
                postData: { 
                IdParam: function () 
                  { return $('#LogID').val(); } 
                },
                jsonReader: {
                    repeatitems: false,
                    id: 'LogID',
                    records: 'TotalRecords',
                    total: 'TotalPages',
                    page: 'CurrentPage',
                    root: 'Rows'
                },
                loadError: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    messageBox('Error', 'Error occurred loading data.');
                },
                height: 'auto',
                width: 'auto'
            });

        });
}   

Report Controller Method
         public ActionResult GetData(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows, int IdParam){}
```

I am trying to load only the needed data from the database ...so when the first page is displayed I am getting 20 rows from db then when the user clicks on next button in the grid I am again hitting the db call and getting next 20 rows now if I debug the method I can see my data coming into the method call but the grid goes to the 2nd page and displays nothing. I mean that the grid is showing the loading sign and then just nothing happens even for the last button I don't get any data but on pager it shows total 100 pages and I can keep going next but only the page no. increments there is no data displayed in the grid..
    any help will be appreciated...I tried to read about the Onpaging event but not able to figure out how to implement it in this scenario..

Quick Observation:
If I change the row count from 20 to 5 10 or 50 that gets the data and displays on the first page its just that the next pages are not getting displayed...

Controller Method:

```
     int pageSize = rows;
     int pageIndex = page - 1;
     int totalPages = 0;

     //call to the db using Entity FrameWork..
     var Log = SERVICE.GetData_sp(IdParam,sidx,sord,page,rows,total).ToList()
     var totalCount = Convert.ToInt32(total.Value); //converting because I am getting it as Output parameter from the Store-Proc in objet.parameter type.
    totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(totalCount / (float)pageSize);

JqGridData gridData = new JqGridData { CurrentPage = page, TotalPages = totalPages, TotalRecords = totalCount };//getting the correct values as I cross checked it by just exec the store-proc.
 //storing data in gridData obj from Log.  
    return Json(gridData);
```

Comment: First of all you should fix JavaScript code inside of `postData`: You should use `postData: { IdParam: function () { return $('#LogID').val(); } }`instead of `postData: { IdParam: function () return $('#LogID').val(); }`

Comment: sorry tht was a typo..I am using it correctly in my call as you helped me out wit it couple of days back..@Oleg

Comment: Your totalPages assignment seems overly complex. Can you see your controller trying to return different sets of data in response to grid page actions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't show your controller method above but I think you are probably not building in the data for the jqGrid to handle paging.

You should be building and passing to the jqGrid

```
int totalRecords = queryOfData.Count();
```

and then later you would pass that to your grid as a jSon value. Ex

```
var jsonData = new
{
    total = (totalRecords + rows - 1) / rows,
    page = page,
    records = totalRecords,
    rows = (
    ......
```

Comment: I have added the controlled method in the above edit....but I am able to get data it the return method ie..return Json(gridData);..so I dont think that there is any problem in that call

Comment: you were correct I was not passing the correct datalist to the grid.. I was getting the data from the store-proc and then trying to sort it..like this

Comment: items = Log
                        .OrderBy(u => u.LogId)
                        .AsQueryable<T>()
                        .Skip((pageIndex) * pageSize)
                        .Take(pageSize);

Comment: this was making the content blank again..thanks for your time